# running sudo command with forever

Tags: node.js, azure, ubuntu, npm, forever

I have the following command which is used to start my `Node.js` web app:

```
sudo node /home/azureuser/myapp/node_modules/concurrently/src/main.js --kill-others "npm run start-prod" "npm run start-prod-api"
```

When I run this command my web app is successfully started—note, if I run it without the `sudo` prefix it does **not** start since it must start a process that is running on port 80. However, I would like to use [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever/) to run my web app continually. I have tried running this from the app directory:

```
sudo forever -c "node /home/azureuser/myapp/node_modules/concurrently/src/main.js --kill-others \"npm run start-prod\" \"npm run start-prod-api\"" -l forever.log -o out.log -e err.log -a --minUptime 20000 --spinSleepTime 5000 --uid "production" ./
```

When I try this I get the following error:

```
Error: spawn EACCES
  at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
  at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:298:11)
  at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:362:9)
  at spawn (/home/azureuser/myapp/node_modules/concurrently/node_modules/cross-spawn/index.js:87:19)
  at /home/azureuser/myapp/node_modules/concurrently/src/main.js:109:21
  at arrayMap (/home/azureuser/myapp/node_modules/concurrently/node_modules/lodash/index.js:1377:25)
  at Function.map (/home/azureuser/myapp/node_modules/concurrently/node_modules/lodash/index.js:5891:14)
  at run (/home/azureuser/myapp/node_modules/concurrently/src/main.js:105:22)
  at main (/home/azureuser/myapp/node_modules/concurrently/src/main.js:37:5)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/home/azureuser/myapp/node_modules/concurrently/src/main.js:306:1)
  at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
  at startup (node.js:134:18)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
```

When I try adding the sudo inside the `-c` command, it also doesn't work. Additionally I have tried adding this line to a `/etc/init/myapp.conf` file in `Ubuntu` in an attempt to start the process at boot:

```
su - azureuser -c "forever -c \"node /home/azureuser/myapp/node_modules/concurrently/src/main.js --kill-others \\\"npm run start-prod\\\" \\\"npm run start-prod-api\\\"\" -l forever.log -o out.log -e err.log -a --minUptime 20000 --spinSleepTime 5000 --uid \"production\" ./"
```

This does not work either.

It is also **not** an option to write out the `server.js` file instead of `npm run start-prod` in the `forever` command because I use [better-npm-run](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-npm-run) in my `package.json` file to start up the server—aka: I **must** start the web app using `npm run start-prod` and `npm run start-prod-api`.

What am I doing wrong? How can I run this process with admin privileges (so it can run on port 80) and still use forever?

Thank you

Comment: Read about the `sudoers` file. You can add a rule that will allow that specific Linux user to run that specific command as root (or any other user) w/o requiring a password input. http://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password

Comment: @marekful Thanks for the response. Which command would I need to add to the `sudoers` file? `forever`? Or `better-npm-run` so that using port 80 isn't an issue?

Comment: @marekful I tried adding `forever`, `better-npm-run`, and `concurrently` to the `sudoers` file, however I'm still getting the `Error: spawn EACCES` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @marekful said, the solution is add a line in the `/etc/sudoers` via the command `sudo visudo` to allow execute without using `sudo`.

There also is a helpful page https://askubuntu.com/questions/72267/how-to-allow-execution-without-using-the-sudo that you can refer to.

I tried to create and run a shell script file for testing successfully, please see the steps below.

```
~ $ touch cmd.sh
~ $ chmod +x cmd.sh
~ $ vim cmd.sh # Adding the content below, testing for using `apt-get update`

#!/bin/sh
sudo apt-get update

~ $ sudo visudo # Adding a line with the content `<my-user> ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get` at the end of the `sudoers` file; find the path of `apt-get` using `which apt-get`
~ $ ./cmd.sh # it works fine without using password
```

> **Note**: Why do I need to add the `sudo` for `apt-get`? it's special for `apt-get`.

So I think you can try to add a line for the command required `sudo`, such as `node`, etc.

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: @peter-pan-msft Thanks for the reply! I added lines for `npm` and `node` using `sudo visudo` as you suggested. I then tried this command: `sudo forever -l forever.log -o out.log -e err.log -a --minUptime 20000 --spinSleepTime 5000 --uid "production" start -c "sudo npm run start" /home/azureuser/myapp/` and, while I think it's the correct approach, I still get this error: `/home/azureuser/myapp/:26533 - npm ERR! argv "/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin" "/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/npm" "run" "start" "/home/azureuser/myapp/"`. Clearly it's treating the script name (/home/azureuser/myapp/) as an arg.

Comment: @UnknownUser I think the issue might be caused by the current path without `packages.json` for running `npm run start`, and the `sudo` for  `npm` is not necessary. Meanwhile, I suggest you can test these commands manually step by step to make sure which command require the root permission.

Comment: The script name is indeed an argument to the program `node`. In the `suders` file either the full exact command must be given (along with all parameters) or you can also use regex. So in your case, after the `ALL=NOPASSWD:` you have to give full command line with parameters. Sudo will only allow it to be run w/o password if it's an exact match, even a space difference will make it fail.

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT Yes, this worked to allow me to use `sudo` with the my `npm` command. Thank you!